# Can't get value of select box in IE or Chrome?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I've been building my site in FF and just realized that it's not working in IE or Chrome (the Javascript, that is). Using IE's JS debugger I found that it is spitting out the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined ...
```

For the following code:

```
var myvar = document.getElementById("selectboxid").value;
```

It works fine in FF, but not in IE or Chrome.

The HTML for the select box looks like this:

```
<select name="selectboxid" id="selectboxid" size="1" autocomplete="off" tabindex="5" >
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
...
```

Am I doing something wrong? If so, why does it work fine in FF?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML too?

Comment: try it like this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1085801/1499781

Comment: I think @Jeff has the answer you need.

Comment: @KevinBoucher - maybe.. I just tried it and I'm getting an error. See my comment below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use this:

```
var myvar = document.getElementById("selectboxid");
var selectedValue = myvar.options[myvar.selectedIndex].value; //This will get the selected value of the select box
```

example to implement this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="selectboxid" id="selectboxid" onchange="alertValue()" size="1" autocomplete="off" tabindex="5">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function alertValue() //this function will only be called when the value of select changed.
    {
        var myvar = document.getElementById("selectboxid");
        var selectedValue = myvar.options[myvar.selectedIndex].value; //This will get the selected value of the select box
        alert(selectedValue);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: I just tried this and am getting the error "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'options': object is null or undefined ..."

Comment: what browser are you using? when did you call the javascript? before or after the select element?

Comment: It appears that the element in question is not present when the code is run. Jeff's suggestion works as expected in jsFiddle (in Chrome).

Comment: @JeffRobertDagala - I'm trying it in IE9 and Chrome. The javascript is in the html file at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @KevinBoucher - the code is run when a checkbox is checked, so the page has been loaded for a long time when the code runs.

Comment: can you post your script when the checkbox was checked?

Comment: updated my answer with a sample on how to implement it. it works on IE9 and Chrome Version 22

Comment: Jeff, thanks so much for your help. I found a stupid little typo in my code that was breaking it. After correcting that, your code worked. Thanks!